# Craftsman lawn tractor

Tags: lawnmower, craftsman

I was driving my lawn tractor when it just stop moving. It did not matter what gear I was in, it was not going anywhere. I removed the mower deck so that I can see under the tractor. I first checked to see if the belt had slipped off the transaxle pulley - it was ok. I then checked the clutch mechanism to see if it was damaged, everything was working as it should. Next was the idler pulley and it was working fine. I started the tractor and put pressure on the belt (the tractor was in gear) and the tractor moved. So, the transaxle is not the problem. To be fair, I do not recommend you do this. I had replaced the drive belt about three years ago. So I do not believe that the belt is bad. I never saw a belt go bad that fast. Usually there is a warning sign like slipping or a squeal sound. Any ideas because I am lost as to what it is.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a spring on the pulley arm which provides the belt tension. When you pull the handle or push the clutch pedal to release the clutch, you are putting pressure on this spring, then the spring brings it all back together so the belt no longer slips. It sounds as thought this spring may have come off.

Comment: Pollster, The spring is in place and function properly.

Comment: Ok, had time to take a closer look at the problem, and what I found was that the clutch pulley was damaged and the belt was holding it in place.